# Can't run commitlint in husky with another custom command

Tags: javascript, npm, husky, git-husky, commitlint

How can I have two precommit hooks in husky? I'm looking to use commitlint along side a custom script defined in my package.json. I have installed husky and have a pre-commit script in the .husky folder. Here is what I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx commitlint --edit 
npm run mycommand
```

I tried `npx commitlint --edit && npm run mycommand` I have also tried removing the commitlint command in this file and adding a second file `commit-msg` in my .husky folder with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx commitlint --edit $1
```

When when I run these the custom command runs but commitlint does not check the message.

How can I run commitlint with my custom command?

Answer (score 0):

run this cmd in terminal

```
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg  'npx --no -- commitlint --edit ${1}'
```

it will create a commit-msg file in .husky folder and then test with git commit msg